# Why wasn't Naruto adopted?

Tags: naruto

Why wasn't naruto adopted when he was young, I mean if he is by himself, the 9 tails power might come out without anyone realizing. If he had a family unit, he would have been able to control his loneliness and therefore maybe helping him control his 9 tails power better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general stigma of Naruto having the 9-tails made people fear him. It's a core point of his character development and central to the story of how he travels the path of deliquent ninja - Hokage and the villages strongest.

In reality it would make sense for him to be adopted but in actuality it would ruin the plot entirely.